# getting system level error in solaris system

Tags: solaris, disk

I am getting below errors, what does it means?

```
Oct 19 01:02:25 amra02 scsi: [ID 107833 kern.warning] WARNING: /pci@7c,0/pci10de,377@f/pci1077,142@0/fp@0,0/disk@w5006016841e00513,0 (sd6):
Oct 19 01:02:25 amra02  drive offline
Oct 19 01:02:25 amra02 scsi: [ID 107833 kern.warning] WARNING: /pci@7c,0/pci10de,377@f/pci1077,142@0/fp@0,0/disk@w5006016841e00513,0 (sd6):
Oct 19 01:02:25 amra02  drive offline
Oct 19 01:02:25 amra02 scsi: [ID 107833 kern.warning] WARNING: /pci@7c,0/pci10de,377@f/pci1077,142@0/fp@0,0/disk@w5006016841e00513,0 (sd6):
Oct 19 01:02:25 amra02  drive offline
Oct 19 01:03:07 amra02 scsi: [ID 107833 kern.warning] WARNING: /pci@7c,0/pci10de,377@f/pci1077,142@0/fp@0,0/disk@w5006016041e00513,0 (sd5):

Oct 17 19:53:19 amra02 scsi: [ID 107833 kern.warning] WARNING: /scsi_vhci/disk@g6006016060702d0051a04cd7773de411 (sd23):
Oct 17 19:53:19 amra02  Command failed to complete...Device is gone
Oct 17 19:53:19 amra02 scsi: [ID 107833 kern.warning] WARNING: /scsi_vhci/disk@g6006016060702d0051a04cd7773de411 (sd23):
Oct 17 19:53:19 amra02  Command failed to complete...Device is gone
Oct 17 19:53:19 amra02 scsi: [ID 107833 kern.warning] WARNING: /scsi_vhci/disk@g6006016060702d0051a04cd7773de411 (sd23):
Oct 17 19:53:19 amra02  Command failed to complete...Device is gone
Oct 17 20:03:19 amra02 scsi: [ID 107833 kern.warning] WARNING: /scsi_vhci/disk@g6006016060702d0051a04cd7773de411 (sd23):
Oct 17 20:03:19 amra02  Command failed to complete...Device is gone
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you loose connectivity (i.e. access to you disk)

```
 5006016841e00513
```

id a clariion controller, and

```
 6006016060702d0051a04cd7773de411
```

is a LUN (or disk) on you SAN.

- vendor CLARIION
- extension 060702d0051a04cd7773de411
- CI:LDEV (16) e4:11 (10) 228 - 17

you should either check your hardware, or if harware is OK, zonning configuration on SAN switch.